# Reduce the Size of Matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

In various operational and manually-run Python scripts, I produce thousands of plots of California every day using matplotlib's Basemap:

```
mp = Basemap(width=1284000,height=1164000,projection='lcc',lat_1=30.,lat_2=60,\
             lat_0=37,lon_0=-120.5,resolution='c',rsphere=6370000.00)
# fill data: lats, lons, grid
cs = orb.pcolor(lons,lats,grid,cmap=cm.jet,norm=colors.LogNorm(),latlon=True)
mp.drawcounties()
```

However, I lose dozens of hours of computing time every single day to loading these large basemaps that cover the entire world. All I need is the counties in California, but I end up loading all the counties in the world into memory. I love how flexible this library is, but it is officially too slow.

- How could I produce these maps faster?
- Could I somehow create a cropped version of the matplotlib `Basemap`, with only California?
- Is there a faster, non-matplotlib way to create geo-referenced plots?

[image: example California plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I produce these maps faster?

You are already using the lowest resolution ("c"). You can change the "area_thresh" argument, but I don't think that'll help much. You'll probably have to work on the way you're plotting the data itself.

> Could I somehow create a cropped version of the matplotlib Basemap, with only California?

You can download a custom map of California and plot only that. Basemap comes with basic world maps, but you can use maps from other sources. It should be easy to get one googling "california shapefile". Use the "readshapefile" method in [mpl_toolkits.basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.basemap) to load it.

[This notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rjtavares/numbers_arent_people/blob/master/experiments/Plotting%20with%20Basemap%20and%20Shapefiles.ipynb) shows how to work with readshapefile and with an alternative method (the pyshp module).

> Is there a faster, non-matplotlib way to create geo-referenced plots?

I've heard good things about [Vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent), but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Are you sure `readshapefile` would help? It looks to me like I have to create the `Basemap` before I could do that anyway. Right?

Comment: @theJollySin You can create the Basemap just for the projection, without drawing coastlines/counties/states. The empty Basemap will allow you to plot using coordinates, which will help a lot :)

Comment: That works great! Could I speed this up further by... pickling the shapefile? I'm afraid I don't know how to load a pickled object into the basemap though.

Comment: I have an uncommented iPython Notebook with my experiments with shapefiles (using two different methods: readshapefile and direct plotting using LineCollection) which would probably help you. I'll try to edit it a little bit and share it later today.

Comment: @theJollySin ok, [here it is](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rjtavares/numbers_arent_people/blob/master/experiments/Plotting%20with%20Basemap%20and%20Shapefiles.ipynb). Let me know if it helped.